# How do I reference a table twice when creating an indexed view? Can I enforce uniqueness based on 2 tables and multiple rows without it?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, indexing, azure-sql-database

**EDIT:** Added in sample data that I am trying to disallow.

This question is similiar to this: [Cannot create a CLUSTERED INDEX on a View because I'm referencing the same table twice, any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011595/cannot-create-a-clustered-index-on-a-view-because-im-referencing-the-same-table) but the answer there doesn't help me. I'm trying to enforce uniqueness, and so an answer of "don't do that" without an alternative doesn't help me progress.

Problem Example (Simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Object]
(
   Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   OrgId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attribute]
(
   Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Name NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectAttribute]
(
   Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
   ObjectId INT NOT NULL,
   AttributeId INT NOT NULL,
   Value NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT FK_ObjectAttribute_Object FOREIGN KEY (ObjectId) REFERENCES [Object] (Id),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ObjectAttribute_Attribute FOREIGN KEY (AttributeId) REFERENCES Attribute (Id)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUX_ObjectAttribute ON [dbo].[ObjectAttribute] ([ObjectId], [AttributeId])
GO

CREATE VIEW vObject_Uniqueness
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    ObjectBase.OrgId
    , CAST(OwnerValue.Value AS NVARCHAR(256)) AS OwnerValue
    , CAST(NameValue.Value AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS NameValue
FROM [dbo].[Object] ObjectBase
INNER JOIN [dbo].ObjectAttribute OwnerValue
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Attribute OwnerAttribute
        ON OwnerAttribute.Id = OwnerValue.AttributeId
        AND OwnerAttribute.Name = 'Owner'
    ON OwnerValue.ObjectId = ObjectBase.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].ObjectAttribute NameValue
    INNER JOIN [dbo].Attribute NameAttribute
        ON NameAttribute.Id = NameValue.AttributeId
        AND NameAttribute.Name = 'Name'
    ON NameValue.ObjectId = ObjectBase.Id
GO

/*
Cannot create index on view "[Database].dbo.vObject_Uniqueness". The view contains a self join on "[Database].dbo.ObjectAttribute".
*/
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IUX_vObject_Uniqueness
ON vObject_Uniqueness (OrgId, OwnerValue, NameValue)
GO

DECLARE @Org1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
DECLARE @Org2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT [dbo].[Object]
(
    OrgId
)
VALUES
    (@Org1) -- Id: 1
    , (@Org2) -- Id: 2
    , (@Org1) -- Id: 3

INSERT [dbo].[Attribute]
(
    Name
)
VALUES
    ('Owner') -- Id: 1
    , ('Name') -- Id: 2
    --, ('Others')

-- Acceptable data.
INSERT [dbo].[ObjectAttribute]
(
    AttributeId
    , ObjectId
    , Value
)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Jeremy Pridemore') -- Owner for object 1 (Org1).
    , (2, 1, 'Apple') -- Name for object 1 (Org1).
    , (1, 2, 'John Doe') -- Owner for object 2 (Org2).
    , (2, 2, 'Pear') -- Name for object 2 (Org2).

-- Unacceptable data.
-- Org1 already has an abject with an owner value of 'Jeremy' and a name of 'Apple'
INSERT [dbo].[ObjectAttribute]
(
    AttributeId
    , ObjectId
    , Value
)
VALUES
    (1, 3, 'Jeremy Pridemore') -- Owner for object 3 (Org1).
    , (2, 3, 'Apple') -- Name for object 3 (Org1).

-- This is the bad data. I want to disallow this.
SELECT
    OrgId, OwnerValue, NameValue
FROM vObject_Uniqueness
GROUP BY OrgId, OwnerValue, NameValue
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

DROP VIEW vObject_Uniqueness
DROP TABLE ObjectAttribute
DROP TABLE Attribute
DROP TABLE [Object]
```

This example will create the error:

`Msg 1947, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot create index on view "TestDb.dbo.vObject_Uniqueness". The view contains a self join on "TestDb.dbo.ObjectAttribute".`

As this shows, I'm using an attribute system with 2 tables to represent one object and it's values. The existence of the object and the OrgId on an object are on the main table, and the rest of the values are attributes on the secondary table.

First of all, I don't understand why this says there is a self join. I'm joining from `Object` to `ObjectAttribute` twice. No where am I going from a table to that same table in an `ON` clause.

Second, is there a way to make this work? Or way to enforce the uniqueness that I'm going f or here? The end result that I want is that, by `Object.OrgId`, I have no two `Object` rows that have `ObjectAttribute` records referencing them providing the same 'Owner' and 'Name' values. So OrgId, Owner, and Name values need to be unique for any given `Object`.

Comment: I guess suggesting to you that you abandon EAV (for at least the Name and Owner attributes) is also off of your list. Having real columns for those attributes in the `ObjectBase` table would make implementing this constraint trivial.

Comment: And to your first question, it really doesn't matter what's in the `ON` clauses - by the time you introduce the join to `ObjectAttribute` that you've aliased as `NameValue`, the "thing" to the left of the join isn't `Object`/`ObjectBase` - it's the already joined combination of `ObjectBase`, `ObjectAttribute` (aliased as `OwnerValue`) and `Attribute` (aliased as `OwnerAttribute`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the clarification. I wouldn't be opposed to making them columns on Object if they could also be kept in sync with the rows on ObjectAttribute. Since the only way I can think to do that is a trigger on both tables, and that doesn't seem like a good solution, I don't want to use columns when that would allow the row value and the column value of the same thing to become out of sync. I'm doing some decent searches on millions of rows and I'm not sure about the code complexity and performance that mixing the attribute rows with columns would bring.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Can you provide sample data and a sample result?  It might be possible to eliminate the second join by changing AND OwnerAttribute.Name = 'Owner' to AND OwnerAttribute.Name IN ('Owner', 'Name') and then pivitoing to get the results into a single row.

Comment: @Vulcronos I added in the bad data with comments, and a select that identifies the bad data. Does that help? Since I can't use PIVOT or COUNT in an indexed view according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx, I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Wow, didn't realize you couldn't even use PIVOT.  Why do you want to index this view?  Just performance?   Possibly we could try to get performance up without an indexed view.  Do the final results have to be in one row per OrgId?

Comment: @Vulcronos The view isn't even meant to be used. It's a means to an end of enforcing uniqueness. I don't want to be able to have more that one `dbo.Object` per `dbo.Object.OrgId` that has the same values over on `dbo.ObjectAttribute` for the `'Name'` and `'Owner'` attributes. I was using a view because if I can represent the values I care about and put a unique index on the view, that will enforce uniqueness on the values the view is selecting, even though they're on different tables.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Ah, do you just want to change the structure of your data?  Is this really a many to many relationship?  Or does each attribute belong to one object and each object have two attributes?

Comment: @Vulcronos Each object can have N attributes. It can only have each attribute one time. So only one 'Name' value, one 'Owner' value, one 'Price' value, etc. Users will be able to define new `dbo.Attribute` records which will define which attributes that objects can have values for. 1 object to many attributes. These two attributes are special though and they (as a pair) should be unique to all objects that are for the same OrgId. If I can find a way to rework my schema while still maintaining my flexibility in a performance-acceptable way, I'd be good with that.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Just to be clear, what is ObjectAttribute do?  Also, maybe you could define a view just on ObjectAttribute and Attribute since ObjectAttribute has the object id, you might not actually need the Object table.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't believe that you can create an index over `NVARCHAR(MAX)` fields that are too long. I think you're out of luck if your requirement is that hold this many characters. My version of Sql Server won't even allow me to create a simple index over the value column in the ObjectAttribute table.

Comment: @user814064 Edit: If you look at the view I have, it's casting the name value to `NVARCHAR(50)` and the owner value to `NVARCHAR(256)`, which are indexable lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could create helper table for this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ObjectAttributePivot]
(
   Id int primary key,
   OwnerValue  nvarchar(256),
   NameValue nvarchar(50)
)
GO
```

And then create helper trigger to keep data synchronized:

```
create view vw_ObjectAttributePivot
as
    select
        o.Id,
        cast(ov.Value as nvarchar(256)) as OwnerValue,
        cast(nv.Value as nvarchar(50)) as NameValue
    from dbo.Object as o
        inner join dbo.ObjectAttribute as ov on ov.ObjectId = o.Id
        inner join dbo.Attribute as ova on ova.Id = ov.AttributeId and ova.Name = 'Owner'
        inner join dbo.ObjectAttribute as nv on nv.ObjectId = o.Id
        inner join dbo.Attribute as nva on nva.Id = nv.AttributeId and nva.Name = 'Name'
GO

create trigger utr_ObjectAttribute on ObjectAttribute
after update, delete, insert
as
begin
    declare @temp_objects table (Id int primary key)

    insert into @temp_objects
    select distinct ObjectId from inserted
    union
    select distinct ObjectId from deleted

    update ObjectAttributePivot set
        OwnerValue = vo.OwnerValue,
        NameValue = vo.NameValue
    from ObjectAttributePivot as o
        inner join vw_ObjectAttributePivot as vo on vo.Id = o.Id
    where
        o.Id in (select t.Id from @temp_objects as t)

    insert into ObjectAttributePivot (Id, OwnerValue, NameValue)
    select vo.Id, vo.OwnerValue, vo.NameValue
    from vw_ObjectAttributePivot as vo
    where
        vo.Id in (select t.Id from @temp_objects as t) and
        vo.Id not in (select t.Id from ObjectAttributePivot as t)

    delete ObjectAttributePivot
    from ObjectAttributePivot as o
    where
        o.Id in (select t.Id from @temp_objects as t) and
        o.Id not in (select t.Id from vw_ObjectAttributePivot as t)
end
GO
```

After that, you can create unique view:

```
create view vObject_Uniqueness
with schemabinding
as
    select
        o.OrgId,
        oap.OwnerValue,
        oap.NameValue
    from dbo.ObjectAttributePivot as oap
        inner join dbo.Object as o on o.Id = oap.Id
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IUX_vObject_Uniqueness
ON vObject_Uniqueness (OrgId, OwnerValue, NameValue)
GO
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59dc3/3)</kbd>**

Comment: I like this idea the best for me. I have a validation schema in which I could put this in. I like that it's explicit, and by failing the insert in the trigger due to the UK fail, it'll fail bad data from ever entering. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue that we have here, enforcing the type of uniqueness you are going for, is in trying to answer the question, "When is it a violation?" Consider this:

- Your database is loaded with the first two objects you reference in
  your example (Org1 and Org2)
- Now we INSERT ObjectAttribute(AttributeId, ObjectId, Value) VALUES (1, 3, 'Jeremy Pridemore')

Is this a violation? Based on what you have told me, I would say "no": we could go on to INSERT ObjectAttribute(AttributeId, ObjectId, Value) VALUES (2, 3, 'Cantalope'), and that would presumably be fine, right? So, we can't know whether the current statement is valid unless & until we know what the next statement is going to be. But there is no guarantee we will ever issue the second statement. Certainly there is no way of knowing what it will be at the time we are making up our minds whether the first statement is OK.

Should we, then, disallow free standing insertions of the type I am talking about-- where an "owner" entry is inserted, but with no simultaneous corrosponding "name" entry? To me, that is only workable approach to what you are trying to do here, and the only way to enforce that type of constraint is with a trigger.

Something like this:

```
DROP TRIGGER TR_ObjectAttribute_Insert
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ObjectAttribute_Insert ON dbo.ObjectAttribute
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @objectsUnderConsideration TABLE (ObjectId INT PRIMARY KEY);
    INSERT INTO @objectsUnderConsideration(ObjectId)
    SELECT DISTINCT ObjectId FROM inserted; 

    DECLARE @expectedObjectAttributeEntries TABLE (ObjectId INT, AttributeId INT);
    INSERT INTO @expectedObjectAttributeEntries(ObjectId, AttributeId)
    SELECT o.ObjectId, a.Id AS AttributeId
    FROM @objectsUnderConsideration o
        CROSS JOIN Attribute a; -- cartisean join, objects * attributes

    DECLARE @totalNumberOfAttributes INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Attribute);

    -- ensure we got what we expect to get
    DECLARE @expectedCount INT, @actualCount INT;
    SET @expectedCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @expectedObjectAttributeEntries);
    SET @actualCount = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM @expectedObjectAttributeEntries e 
            INNER JOIN inserted i ON e.AttributeId = i.AttributeId AND e.ObjectId = i.ObjectId
    );  -- if an attribute is missing, we'll have too few; if an object is being entered twice, we'll have too many

    IF @expectedCount < @actualCount
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('Invalid insertion: incomplete set of attribute values', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN 
    END
    ELSE IF @expectedCount > @actualCount
    BEGIN 
        RAISERROR ('Invalid insertion: multiple entries for same object', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN 
    END

    -- passed the check that we have all the necessary attributes; now check for duplicates
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        -- for each object, count exact duplicate preexisting entries; reject if every attribute is a dup
        DECLARE @duplicateAttributeCount TABLE (ObjectId INT, DupCount INT);
        INSERT INTO @duplicateAttributeCount(ObjectId, DupCount)
        SELECT o.ObjectId, (
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM inserted i
                INNER JOIN ObjectAttribute oa
                     ON i.AttributeId = oa.AttributeId
                    AND i.ObjectId = oa.ObjectId
                    AND i.Value = oa.Value
                    AND i.Id <> oa.Id
            WHERE oa.ObjectId = o.ObjectId
        )
        FROM @objectsUnderConsideration o

        IF EXISTS ( 
            SELECT 1
            FROM @duplicateAttributeCount d
            WHERE d.DupCount = @totalNumberOfAttributes
        )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Invalid insertion: duplicates pre-existing entry', 16, 1);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RETURN 
        END
    END
GO
```

The above is not tested; thinking about it, you may need to join out to Object and organize your tests by OrgId instead of ObjectId. You would also need comparable triggers for UPDATE and DELETE. But, hopefully this is at least enough to get you started.

Answer (score -3):

You should consider which Sql Sever edition do you use, this has limitations on indexed views.
see: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(SQL.110).aspx#RDBMS_mgmt**
See indexed views direct querying.
The following steps are required to create an indexed view and are critical to the successful implementation of the indexed view:

1-Verify the SET options are correct for all existing tables that will be referenced in the view.

2-Verify the SET options for the session are set correctly before creating any new tables and the view.

3-Verify the view definition is deterministic.

4-Create the view by using the WITH SCHEMABINDING option.

5-Create the unique clustered index on the view.

Required SET Options for Indexed Views
Evaluating the same expression can produce different results in the Database Engine if different SET options are active when the query is executed. For example, after the SET option CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set to ON, the expression 'abc ' + NULL returns the value NULL. However, after CONCAT_NULL_YIEDS_NULL is set to OFF, the same expression produces 'abc '.